# Mocha tests wrapped in sinon.test are losing access to spy, mock, and stub

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Our tests are organized like this:

```
describe("description", sinon.test(function() {
    const harness = this;
    it("should do something", function() {
        // do something with harness.spy, harness.mock, harness.stub
    });
}));
```

When run, these tests are all failing with `TypeError: harness.spy is not a function`. I've added some logs and found that `harness.spy` exists and is a function before the function passed to `it` is called, but inside the function passed to `it`, `harness.spy` is `undefined`.

Any help understanding what is happening here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order in which Mocha executes your code. Wrapping the callback to `describe` with `sinon.test` cannot work. That's because the callbacks to all `describe` finish executing *before* any of the tests in `it` even start executing. The way `sinon.test` works, it creates a new sandbox, instruments `this` with some of the methods of the sandbox (`spy`, `stub`, etc.), then calls its callback, and when the callback returns, *`sinon.test` removes from `this` the methods that it added*.

So necessarily, any of the setup performed by `sinon.test` wrapping a `describe` callback will be undone before any of the tests are run. Here's an example where I've put some `console.log`. You'll see both `console.log` statements execute before any test is run.

```
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe("description", sinon.test(function() {
    const harness = this;
    it("should do something", function() {
    });

    console.log("end of describe");
}));

console.log("outside");
```

You need to wrap the callbacks you pass to `it`, instead, like this:

```
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe("description", function() {
    it("should do something", sinon.test(function() {
        this.spy();
    }));
});

console.log("outside");
```

If the lifetime of the sandbox created by `sinon.test` does not work for you, then you have to create your sandbox and clean it "manually", like this:

```
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe("description", function() {
    let sandbox;
    before(function () {
        sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    });
    after(function () {
        sandbox.restore();
    });
    it("should do something", function() {
        sandbox.spy();
    });
    it("should do something else", function() {
        // This uses the same sandbox as the previous test.
        sandbox.spy();
    });
});
```